# Does session.gc-maxlifetime restart if Session_Start() is called again? or is it calculated from the first time session is created?

Tags: php, session

According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime):

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which
> data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage
> collection may occur during session start (depending on
> session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor). Defaults to 1440 (24
> minutes).

but is this period of seconds calcuated from the first time `Session_Start()` is called? or does the time restart after `Session_start()` is called again, or after some sort of interaction with `$_SESSION` is made?

If it is calculated from the first time session is created, is there a way to restart this so that users dont face errors from trying to interact with session variables that have been reset to null?

Comment: Sessions may be accidentally removed. If a user faces errors due to null session variables, it indicates that your code is not strong enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is : the session lifetime's `end-time` will be "re-calculated" when the start_session() is called again.

Note: `session.gc_maxlifetime` specifies the `maximum` `lifetime` of `session` (gc stands for `garbage collection`)

It is because the garbage collection process is designed to abandon "inactive" sessions , which is obviously one of the measures of security.

For example, if you set the following in your php.ini and then restart the httpd , the system will 100% perform garbage collection (session.gc_probability/session.gc_divisor =1) whenever the time reaches the lifetime timeout which is 60 seconds

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=60
session.gc_probability = 1000
session.gc_divisor = 1000
```

Now, if you run , on your browser this php (session1.php):

```
<?php session_start();

$_SESSION["var1"]="Stack Overflow";
```

if you then , wait after 60 seconds, and run the following (session2.php), you will notice that the system echos nothing , because $_SESSION["var1"] is destroyed due to garbage collection

```
<?php session_start();

echo $_SESSION["var1"];
```

However, if you run session1.php and then wait for 59 seconds and immediately run session2.php, you will notice that `echo $_SESSION["var1"];` will display the word "Stack Overflow", and if you wait for another 59 seconds and run session2.php again, it will display the word "Stack Overflow" again .... until one time you run the session2.php AFTER 60 seconds, then the session is gone

Note: If you really did the above test, remember to set back the gc_probability, gc_divisor and gc_maxlifetime to the default values after you have done the test, otherwise I believe 60 seconds are too short for the session life time under normal circumstances

Comment: The way this is described is a bit misleading.  First of all, session variables don't have a lifetime.  The entire session, which by default is stored in a file, will either be deleted or not based on the max lifetime.  So it's a simple measurement --- is an attribute of the file on the filesystem older than the max lifetime or not.  Again by default, using files, what it the garbage collector looks at, is the mtime of all the session files in the session storage location.  If garbage collection runs, then it will delete files with mtimes older than current time - gc_maxlifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: **You can't call `session_start()` twice during the same session.**

Long story:

Garbage collector may be called at any point in time, so the session's file timestamp (the file inside your php temp directory) is the only way to tell if the data will be considered garbage during the next execution of `GC`.

Now, if you try to execute this:

```
<?php
while (true) {
    session_start();
    sleep(5);
}
```

PHP will yield `session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active`

This implies that you **need** to close your current session after calling `session_start()` again. Once you call `session_start()` (and resume your session) it will update your session file's timestamp thus resetting the timer for that session.

You can alter the behavior of the current session handler by implementing a [custom session handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) as well.